# MYSQL Query Left Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Here is my query

```
select t1.*, t2.name as customer, t2.name as vendor from order t1
left join contact t2
on t2.id = t1.cid and t2.id = t1.vendid
where t1.id = 22
```

- contact_Table => id, Name
- order_Table => id, orderName, cid, vendid

My problem is I want to select an order where `order.id = 22` and instead of `order.cid, order.vendid` I want their names which exist in contact table.

Above query result with `customer = vendor = NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. The query will result with customer=vendor=null because you are setting `t2.id = t1.cid and t2.id=t1.vendid`, or t2.id=t1.cid=t1.vendid. Since I guess no order has the same vendor and customer ID, your query wont work.

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name as cust, t3.name as vendor
FROM order t1
LEFT JOIN contact t2 ON (t2.id=t1.cid)
LEFT JOIN contact t3 on (t3.id=t1.vendid)
WHERE t1.id=22
```

This way you link twice with the contacts table, one of them to get the customer info and one to get the vendor info.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds here like you actually want two separate joins to the contact table, one for the customer and one for the vendor, it also helps to make your table aliases more meaningful to avoid confusion:

```
SELECT o.*, c.name as customer, v.name as vendor 
FROM order o
LEFT JOIN contact c on (c.id = o.cid) 
LEFT JOIN contact v ON  (v.id = o.vendid)
WHERE o.id = 22
```